# Where do you store your sprint goal statement in TFS 2012 update 2?

Tags: tfs, scrum, sprint

It does not appear that the TFS Scrum template contains a field to store the sprint goal. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sprint` work item, used in TFS 2010 with the [MS Scrum 1.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e) process template, was removed from the Scrum process template 2.0 of TFS 2012. Essentially it allowed entering sprint dates, goals and retrospective.

However in TFS 2012, you configure the sprint schedule as part of the new [Agile Planning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189203.aspx) feature, making the Sprint work item redundant.

So your options for storing the goals\retrospective in TFS 2012:

- Use a `Task` work item (Title, Description fields)
- Add [custom field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400654.aspx) in the `Product Backlog Item`
- Import the `Sprint` work item via the [witadmin importwitd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) command \ [Process Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718795.aspx)
- Use SharePoint integration - store as a document

Comment: Since Team Projects can also use any URL as the project portal and not just SharePoint, you might also look into a wiki.

Comment: To me the sprint goal is a short statement that should be displayed next to the sprint dates or similar - not a document or a link :)  

If the sprints are automatically numbered the sprint name could be used to store the goal - though I guess they're not automatically numbered?

Answer (score 1):

This VSTS/TFS extension does exactly what you're asking, it enables you to set a goal for each sprint: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keesschollaart.sprint-goal

*Full disclosure: I'm the author!*